# Flashforge Adventure 3 printer

Tags: flashforge-adventurer-3

Recently bought the printer for my son, right from the start it didn’t print well. We made some adjustments and got it working somewhat but now it keeps printing (Benchy) only half way up and starts knocking off top half over leaving it unfinished.
The bottom heat plate looks to be crooked maybe by a 1/16” (1.6 mm) to 1/8”(3.2 mm) off.

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to 3D Printing.SE! Please expand by [edit] what adjustments you made and please add some pictures of the failed print, preferably just after failing on the heated bed.

Comment: Nick, welcome to 3D Printing SE.  I concur with Oscar.  Descriptions of 3D printing disasters and problems are much more helpful when accompanied by photos.  If the bed seems warped, take a picture of it against a straightedge.  If an anomaly occurs during printing, photos of the result soon enough after the problem occurs so that it all isn't lost is a birdsnest of stray filament may help people understand what has happened.  I look forward to your participation here, and your son's.  All levels of experience are welcome, and helpful!